# How to synchronize iAds and AdMob ads?

Tags: ios, admob, iad

As far as I can see iAds have an update period of 30 seconds, while for AdMob ads you can set the refresh rate yourself to periods between 60 and 120 seconds. If you want both iAds and AdMob ads, how do you synchronize them so iAd does not try to get a new ad while still displaying an AdMob one, or vice versa?

Of course one could remove the iAd banner for the duration of the AdMob try, but there is a delay before an ad banner actually gets ads served, so Apple recommends to create one banner and keep that around.

The examples I have seen usually do actually remove the iAd banner from the superview when an iAd is not available, and then switch completely to AdMob. But, just one failed iAd does not mean there are no iAds at all. Still, if you switch to AdMob that way you may effectively be away from iAds for 60-120 seconds, or till AdMob tells you it really has no more ads. (DOES AdMob actually tell you there are no more ads? The test app does not get that signal..)

Or is this a non-issue because there simply are not that many adverts? So far the fill rates for iAds in my apps are 95-99%, so that looks fine. My main goal is to have my free Apps display ads in non-iAd regions too. (Currently I don't distribute free versions in non-iAd regions.) I could detect in my App that over time relatively few iAds are served, and then favour AdMob over iAds.

Any ideas and insights are very welcome!

PS: I'm aware of AdWhirl, but that is a Google service, and I'd prefer to stay in control a bit myself.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you *can* set the refresh rate of AdMob ads to 30 seconds too, and that is what I do.

I'm doing some internal statistics on the success of fulfilling ad requests for both iAds and AdMob, and based on that I give either iAds or AdMob the preference above the other, only switching to the other system after it failed to retrieve an ad 2 or 3 times.